# Is a Bitlocker encrypted drive safe to dispose?

Tags: security, encryption, bitlocker, hard-drive-recovery, brute-force

**Based on the nowadays public knowledge about the strongness of the Bitlocker encryption** - and **supposing the user thinks the Bitlocker password is strong enough to make bruteforce unviable with the current technology** - is it safe to dispose a Bitlocker encrypted device without a safe deletion process?

Making the question more explicit: **is the bypass process all about plain bruteforce, or are there known factors which make the process easier?** I mean, for example known Windows files or known data structures on the NTFS partition which can help the attacker make assumptions about the passwords to try.

Thank you!

*NOTE:
Answers about how safe can the decission be to consider the viability of the bruteforce is off topic. 
Answers about how the data is not deleted when you format a drive are off topic.
Comments regarding how sensitive is the data are off-topic. 
Advices about if it's better to be conservative and take efforts on erasig the data are also not asked.
Comments regarding the ability to recover data of an already erased hard drive with advanced techniques are off-topic. 
Comments regarding how good security professionals are you or you or you or I are totally off topic. 
This question is about the strongness of the Bitlocker encryption and the potential weakness that can be caused by previsible data or partition internals. 
This question is about a fact I don't know and I want to add to my knowledge.
thank you :)*

Comment: No it's not safe enough for real sensitive data - the drive needs to be 7-passed and destroyed.

Comment: Even if you shred everything it can still sometimes be recovered. I smash all my drives with a hammer, takes about 2-5 minutes.

Comment: @Raystafarian, I bet you can't find a citation that shows data stored on a current-technology hard drive and overwritten 6 times has ever been successfully recovered. In fact, I'd wager you can't find a citation showing a single erasure.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton I'd wager you're not responsible for real sensitive data. [You can read up on SSD recovery if you want](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/fast11/tech/full_papers/Wei.pdf).

Comment: I will be honest, your question is not clear, you should clarify it.

Comment: @Raystafarian, that paper shows that SSDs make it hard to overwrite data on an SSD. That's true, but not what I asked. Anyway, to avoid taking these comments off-topic, I won't press for you to answer the question I asked. Note that I may answer OP and you may disagree with my answer.

Comment: @all added some claryfying comments. IMHO I think the question is very clarified and can be answered. But when we talk about this kind of things we always start thinking that the OP is just a kiddie which knows nothing about security and begin to make comments about good practices or real wlrkd examples to educate the OP. This is not about that. This is about a question with some parameters which carry to an answer. Thank you folks ;)

Comment: Also consider this three year old question on security.SE [about BitLocker's security](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40441/is-windows-bitlocker-secure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are disposing of a drive and want to ensure the data is not leaked.

If the data was stored in plain-text (i.e. not encrypted), you would have to ensure the data was 'shredded'. Just formatting the drive would not be sufficient; formatting doesn't overwrite the data, which is why there are 'unformat' utilities.

Instead, you'd consider a tool like [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/). There are various erasure standards and as @Raystafarian points out, you can be all but sure the data is unrecoverable if you do a 7-pass shred. In truth, there are no reports of successful recovery after even a single pass on a modern mechanical hard drive, but it often pays to be conservative.

Matters are more complicated when considering SSDs. See [this article](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/fast11/tech/full_papers/Wei.pdf) (thanks to @Raystafarian for the link) for more information. SSDs remap blocks, which means you can overwrite all the data on the drive and some of the old data may have been remapped and not actually overwritten. DBAN doesn't handle SSDs.

Okay, but this isn't what you are doing. You have stored the data protected using Bitlocker and aren't planning on shredding or even overwriting the data at all. What you are suggesting is actually similar to how SSDs often implement 'secure erase'. They encrypt all data and then, during the 'secure erase', simply overwrite the block containing the key. **Without the key, there's no practical way to recover the data.**

**This is true in your case, too. You cannot recover the data from a Bitlocker-encrypted drive without knowing the key, assuming no vulnerabilities in the Bitlocker implementation or in the underlying encryption algorithm. The fact that you know a great deal of the plain-text ("known Windows files or known data structures") is irrelevant; the encryption algorithm is strong despite known plaintexts.**

In this case, against most adversaries, I'd suggest just doing a complete (as opposed to a quick) format. Even that shouldn't be necessary, but it's probably a good plan. Against a well-funded government or evil criminal empire? Well, you probably have other problems. And then I'd definitely be wiping the drive (using DBAN or a similar SSD-capable tool) and physically destroying the drive.

Comment: Hope you don't mind I have highlighted what's the real answer to the asked question. <3 thank you for your answer and for rightly understanding the question

Comment: You are welcome to edit my answer. I know I was providing much more detail than you asked. I did so in the hopes it would be useful to others. :)

Comment: I'm not -1 or explicitly disagreeing here, but depending on the data I point to [this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/115092/7559) on the apple encryption case - in which the government did crack and are not releasing the security flaws to be fixed. One would assume (and it may be conspiracy sounding) that government(s) exploit plenty of zero-days without publishing (e.g. [heartbleed](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2014-04-11/nsa-said-to-have-used-heartbleed-bug-exposing-consumers)), so no evidence exists. Just be aware of the sensitivity of data you need destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

Chris gave a nicely comprehensive answer. His advice—particularly on encrypting, securely deleting and if necessary destroying—is sound. As others have mentioned the question depends on your expected adversary and the value of the data. Two corollaries:

1. Computer forensics has developed at a truly astonishing rate. It is difficult to overestime the capabilities of even modest companies.
2. Bitlocker is closed source. Any faith placed in Bitlocker to be effective is [solely based upon the trust of Microsoft and its partners with NDAs](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2015/06/encrypting_wind.html) who have audited the source code. I have now idea what it does, you have no idea what it does and neither does much of the security community (the one's that do can't tell you). Whether or not there are 'backdoors' or weaknesses that can be exploited is speculation, and that's the problem. Its effectiveness is an unknown quantity, one that is anecdotal rather than rigourous.

> supposing the user thinks the Bitlocker password is strong enough to
>   make bruteforce unviable with the current technology

This is a supposition which is by its nature unfounded. It will again be dependant upon the nature of the adversary.

This is a question that involves security and the confidentiality and integrity of data. For you (and most) it may be a question of learning more about the technology. For others reading the question it may well be a matter of life and death. As such anyone reading should be sure to do their research, identify security experts and data security policies used where the highest care is taken and do their best to implement them.

So in answer to

> is the bypass process all about plain bruteforce, or are there known
>   factors which make the process easier?

From the few attacks we've seen published the encryption is bypassed, not broken. It is unknown whether Microsoft or certain Governments have extant side-channel (or other) attacks against Bitlocker; the removal of a component called [the elephant diffuser](https://cryptoservices.github.io/fde/2014/12/08/code-execution-in-spite-of-bitlocker.html) was taken to be a net weakening of the system and could be seen as a precendent for such behaviour.

This question would probably also benefit from being asked on the information security stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

*Just for completeness*, depending on data destruction you can refer to [NIST Special Publication 800-88 Guidelines for Media Sanitation](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-88r1.pdf) - starting on page 26 is **Appendix A - Minimum Sanitation Recommendations** which has **Table A-1 Hard Copy Storage Sanitization**.

Summarized on the table is a non-comprehensive list of Clear, Purge and Destroy methods. A minimum recommendation for clearing is

> *at least one pass of writes with a fixed data value such as zeros. Multiple passes or more complex values may alternatively be used*

This includes any encryption that exists. So "safe to dispose" would not be qulified by just bitlocker. And to destroy the recommendation is

> *shred, disintegrate, pulverize or incinerate.*

These are *minimum requirements* recommended by National Institute of Standards and Technology. If you have no PII, PCI, PHI, proprietary, or otherwise sensitive data - you might not need to worry about this.

Also consider my information security background and my tinfoil hat.

Comment: I like that your answer is quite a different take to mine. Definitely worth my +1.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton yeah, my tinfoil hat has its own tinfoil hat, ha